# Html.DropDownList default selection troubleshoot

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a selection of names, drawn from my database, to which I prepend the option "None" in my Controller:

```
var rtrnStaff = (from st in db.PrmTbl_Staffs
    join sal in db.PrmTbl_Salutations on st.SalutationID equals sal.ID
    where st.Active == true
    select new { st.ID, Name = sal.Desc + ". " + st.Name });

List<SelectListItem> staff = new SelectList(rtrnStaff, "ID", "Name").ToList();
staff.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "None", Value = "0" }));

ViewData["Staff"] = staff;
```

I then present this list as a dropdown multiple times in my View, where each time I feed it a variable containing the ID of the desired default option:

```
@Html.DropDownList(thisSelectID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Staff"], thisStaffID)
```

Using breakpoints, I can see that these variables are being filled correctly (eg. "3", "2", etc.), but in every case the option shown is the first one: "None". Where is my error?

Comment: try using the `.Add()` method

Comment: @Johnx I don't want to use the `Selected=false` arg to bump the "None" option off the selected spot, as there is one case on the View where I *do* actually want it as the default option. Is that what you were getting at, or are there other reasons to use `.Add()`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `DropDownList` you don't have any way to set the selected value but in the list itself. None of the overloads allows to do it.

So, if you only have one list, it's unavoidable to have all the controls with the same selected item.

Most times it's much better, and make the code much more clear to use a view model class for your view, and use `DropDownListFor`.

When you use `DropDowListFor` you set the default property value in the property of the view model, and you don't have to do anything special to set the selected value.

I.e. create a class like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Staff { get; set; }
    public int FirstId { get; set; }
    public int SecondId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your view,

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstId, Model.Staff);
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SecondId, Model.Staff);
```

Create an instance of `MyViewModel`, intialize the list and the Ids, and pass it to the View

```
MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel 
{
    // Initialize here 
};
...
return View("ViewName", model);
```

There are additional advantages: you can use the same view model class as the parameter for the POST action method, and the properties are automatically bound to the corresponding properties, you have Intellisense and a typed view is safer to implement.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use an ID, stored as a variable within a loop, to identify the displayed selection using this example. I have not used DropDownListFor before - can you edit your answer to show it utilising such a variable as shown in my question?

Comment: Show more code of your view, and add some extra eplanation so that I can understand what you're trying to achieve... at first sight it doesn't look very MVC-ish.